# Object and reference creation

Tags: java

If you have

```
Student stud1 = new Student();
```

does that create both a reference and an object of type Student? Would stud1 be the reference of object Student?

Comment: what do you think?  Is there some underlying problem?

Comment: Not necessarily a problem in a specific program I'm wiring. I'm just trying to understand what is being created.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Feel free to add

Comment: Nah, I couldn't have put it as beautifully as another-dave.

Answer (score 4):

> does that create both a reference and an object of type Student?

`new Student()` creates an object.  That creation procedure now has to be able to communicate to its caller what it has created, because after all it's useless to create a thing and not be able to tell you about the thing.

The way in Java to talk about this sort of "what" is called a "reference".   So `new` creates an object and returns a reference to it.   There's really nothing else it could do.

`Student stud1` declares a variable that holds a reference to some object of type Student.  The `=` operator stores the reference returned from `new` into `stud1`.

Saying that a reference is "created" as well as the object seems to be making heavy work of the truism that in order to refer to a thing you need to have a reference to it.  Being able to refer to a thing is surely part of thing-ness.  If there is no reference to a thing, there is effectively no thing.